# Typehints / quicktype alternative for json in python

Tags: python, quicktype

Right now creating code with: `quicktype -l python`

So I can parse my response to code:

```py
data = requests.get(url).json()
data_with_types = top_level_from_dict(data)
print(data_with_types.data.this.works.fine)
```

This has been very helpful with big and messy json responses.

My problems are:

- Code breaks when something changes in data.
- It gets a bit slow with big data.

Is there an alternative solution or a better way to maybe fix this?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Consider Pydantic. It also provides code generation functionality. See: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/datamodel_code_generator/